# Changing values of all decimal fields of a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have an instance of a class, and I want to change values of all decimal fields of that class:

```
var rec = new MyClass();
 rec.GetType()
  .GetFields()
  .Select(field => field.GetValue(rec)
  .Where(value => value is decimal)
  .Select(value => value = GetDecimalValue())
  .ToList();
```

The value of the fields stays unchanged. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are just copying the values. You should do something like this (I didn't compile it and my c# is bit rusty)

```
var rec = new MyClass();
var fields = rec.GetType()
.GetFields()
.Where(value => value.GetValue(rec) is decimal)
.ToList();

foreach(var field in fields) {
     field.setValue(rec, 1.234) 
}
```

Comment: I did this just a minute before you suggested. It works. Thanks )

Answer (score 1):

Just to update the answer with more LINQ and Lambda , I have used the foreach extension method.

```
var rec = new MyClass();
            var fields = rec.GetType()
            .GetFields()
            .Where(value => value.GetValue(rec) is decimal)
            .ToList();

fields.ForEach(fieldInfo => fieldInfo.SetValue(rec, 1.234));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit or extend the class?  If you can I would suggest adding a method to the class, or extending the class such that it performs the logic you require.  Or are you trying to do this to any class that has decimal fields?

Comment: I am trying to do this to a group of classes.